# Update newly inserted non-nullable foreign key, with inserted value of a trigger

Tags: sql-server

I do not know if this is even possible.

At the moment I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_insert_a
ON A
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @expDate datetime2;
DECLARE @identifier uniqueidentifier;
set @expDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE());
set @identifier = NEWID();
INSERT INTO B(UniqueValue, ExpirationDate) VALUES (@identifier, @expDate);
END
```

[EDIT]

The previous trigger will create a record in table "B", when a new record is created in table "A".
That is kinda what I am trying to achieve, but maybe I should try to explain it the other way around:
Before I insert anything into table "A", I want to create a record in table "B", take the id of the newly created record in "B", and set "FK_Bid" to that value.

[image]

[/EDIT]

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to generate a dummy parent row in table B? All this code is going to do is generate a guid value in a new row in table B. There is nothing to associate that with the inserted row of TableA. A clear explanation of what you are trying to do is required to get any real help here.

Comment: Sorry that it was unclear. Getting thoughts into text is not always that easy. I updated my question with a reexplanation of my problem, and a picture of the two tables ...

Comment: OK I get what you are trying to do. The real question now is why? What is the point of creating a row in B? To accomplish this you need to look at the OUTPUT clause. You can do your insert(s) into TableB and use the OUTPUT of that insert to use for TableA. This means you will have to generate an instead of trigger for tableA. The bigger question to me is why? If you are just always going to create a fake parent then maybe the relationship should be rethought or even move the "parent" data into the child rows.

Comment: Well, I redesigned my schema, because it shouldn't have been a "one-to-one", but a "one-to-many" relation.
But thank you very much for your inputs :-)